# how to retrieve source code from .apk file in Android ?

Tags: java, android

I want source code from **.apk** file in Android. I have done half of the part of .apk file.First i have rename the **.apk** file like **HelloWorldPdf.apk.zip** and save into new folder . Then download the **dex2jar** and extract into the same folder then open the command promptand i have typed file path of in command prompt where i have to put **HelloWprldPdf.apk.zip** file `(C:\Document and Settings\bcod\Desktop\Abc\des2jar classes.dex)` and then press the enter button it shows the cmd prompt is =

```
C:\Documents and Settings\bcod\Desktop\Abc>dex2jar-0.0.9.15 Classes.dex
'dex2jar-0.0.9.15' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone help me please.Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Reverse Engineering on Android Apps is not a nice gesture. Please use open source applications and have a look at the source code.

Comment: I guess you can rename the executable to something saner and try again, but yes, this is something that is frowned upon

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQN39X9oTi8 go through this video. This is the best tutorial I found out to get the source code from .apk file. Although the code is obfuscated and hard to read but atleast you get the layouts

Comment: and SO users are so eager to post answers as well..

Comment: if the code is obfuscated it becomes quite difficult to reverse engineer..

Answer (score 4):

You want to reverse engineer the apk file. Okay follow these steps:

1. Download dex2jar file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/).
2. open Command Prompt and change path as : C:\dex2jar and type cd C:\dex2jar and press enter. Place APK file in dex2jar folder after that type dex2jar FlagQuiz_1.1.apk to start decompiling it.
3. Download Java JD_GUI from [here](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui).
4. Open the converted jar file. There list of all classes will be displayed

Comment: @Tazeen Momin Do u find the solution???

Comment: wow! it works but it not give me design(XML) code. if you have any idea please share it.